# Import > Feature Class (multiple) of ArcMap not loading all features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, feature-class

The Import > Feature Class (multiple) option of ArcMap is not loading all my features. When I do this it fails and only loads partial features (only 200k features instead of the full 800k). When I do Import Single Feature it runs with no problems. It is a basic shapefile import to a geodatabase feature class.

I have been doing this type of import for years with no problems and now out of nowhere it seems to be causing me trouble, slowing down my monthly data updates.

Why might this be happening on the import multiple features only?

Comment: What happens when you try using the multiple tool on subsets of the multiple shapefiles (you could use Select _analysis to create the subsets)?  If multiple smaller shapefiles work then it suggests that there may be an issue with the data in one or more of your shapefiles that you need to isolate.

Comment: You should run Check Geometry and/or Repair Geometry on your source shapefiles.

Comment: After a bit of testing i found out that it was not a data issue but a network/server problem. I had to bring all my data to the local machine and the tool ran fine inside of the ESRI environment.